# Arduino IDE not compile .S program to board

Tags: arduino-ide, java, assembly

After answering my previous question correctly I'm getting all sorts of errors when trying to compile the following program:

I'm completely new to both assembly and the arduino IDE so I apologise in advance for any basic errors.

sketch.ino:

```
#include "blink.S"
extern void blink();
void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
blink();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

blink.S file:

```
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0
#include <avr/io.h>         




  .section .text


  ldi r18, 0x20   ; loading 0x20 = 00100000 into register r18
  out DDRB, r18   ; making pin 5 of port B an output

  mov r16, r18    ; copy mask 00100000 also to r16

loop: out PORTB, r16    ; switch on or off the pins of port B
        ; according to bit pattern in r16


  ldi r17, 82   ; 1000ms delay, see below

outer_delay:
  clr r1      
middle_delay:
  clr r2      
inner_delay:        
  dec r2      ; 1 clock tick
  brne inner_delay  ; 2 clock ticks when z!=0, 1 tick when z=0.

  dec r1      ; when this line is reached, about
        ; 256*3 = 768 ticks have been consumed since inner_delay.
  brne middle_delay ; 

  dec r17                 ; when this line is reached, about
        ; 256*256*3 = 196608 ticks have been
        ; consumed since middle delay.
  brne outer_delay  

  eor r16,r18   ; invert bit 5 in r16 using exclusive or.
  rjmp loop   ; jump back to loop.
```

Comment: Try just removing `#include "blink.S"`.

Comment: blink.s is the source of your pain, and removing it will make a big difference, but if you need the assembler then there is normally some sort of keyword to mark the start and end of the assembler and I suspect you .s file might need there _IF_ you need the .s file.  I have no idea of what it is, its a long time since I did ASM and then it was on a PC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things you can try.

First, make sure your assembly code makes the `blink()` function visible
to the linker. blink.S should start like this:

```asm
#define __SFR_OFFSET 0
#include <avr/io.h>         

.section .text
.global blink
blink:
  ; Your assembly code goes below the above label.
```

Next, your sketch file should not try to include the assembly source. It
should only reference it as an external symbol. And note that the symbol
should be declared `extern "C"`.

If your program is a mix of assembly and Arduino code, you could start
with this sketch.ino:

```c++
extern "C" void blink();

void setup() {
    blink();
}

void loop() {}
```

If you are not using the Arduino core library, you could instead write:

```c++
extern "C" void blink();

int main(void)
{
    blink();
    return 0;
}
```

And if you don't want to use C++ at all, you could try to use a dummy or
empty sketch.ino, and rename “blink” to “main” in blink.S.

Answer (score 1):

There's four things I can see wrong (one of which is my fault, actually - I should have mentioned it in the previous question - nevermind).

Firstly you cannot include a .S file in a .INO file. A .S file is assembly, a .INO file is C++. You can't mix the two in one file (and including a file does just that - includes the file verbatim at that point). So remove that `#include`. Otherwise it would be like opening a book written in English only to find the preface is written in Klingon.

Secondly you need to give your function a name. It doesn't have one at the moment. Naming the file is *not* naming the function.

So you need to provide a label at the entry point:

```
  .section .text

blink:    ; << This is the name of the function
  ldi r18, 0x20   ; loading 0x20 = 00100000 into register r18
  out DDRB, r18   ; making pin 5 of port B an output
```

Third you need to export that name as a global symbol:

```
  .section .text
  .global blink ; << This exports the function name

blink:    ; << This is the name of the function
  ldi r18, 0x20   ; loading 0x20 = 00100000 into register r18
  out DDRB, r18   ; making pin 5 of port B an output
```

And finally you have the problem of linkage name munging.  You're linking a C++ file with (ostensibly) a C file - and C++ munges names. So you have to tell your C++ file that the function is not a C++ function, but a C function (which is what I should have mentioned previously):

```
extern "C" void blink(); // << Add the "C" to tell it not to munge the name

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  blink();
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}
```